# Getting Else Statement | Unable To Update Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I've written a code to update course information however the contact isn't being updated and instead I'm getting the else statement. Attached is the if statement for for the "ok" button on the edit course fragment and the Database code

Update Edit Fragment

```
package com.example.v1z0.assignments;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.example.v1z0.assignments.Models.Courses;
import com.example.v1z0.assignments.Utils.DatabaseHelper;

public class EditCourseFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "EditCourseFragment";

    //null pointer evasion//
    public EditCourseFragment(){
        super();
        setArguments(new Bundle());
    }

    private Courses mCourses;
    private EditText mCode, mName, mCredit;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private String mSelectedImagePath;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editcourse, container, false);
        mCode = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etCourseCode);
        mName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etCourseName);
        mCredit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etCourseCredit);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.editCourseToolbar);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started");

        TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textCourseToolbar);
        heading.setText(getString(R.string.edit_course));


        //Toolbar Pre-req//
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mCourses = getCoursesFromBundle();

        if (mCourses != null);
        {
            init();
        }

                                      //Go Back//
        ImageView ivBackArrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ceivBackArrow);
        ivBackArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked back arrow");
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });

                                 //Save//
        ImageView ivCheckMark = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivCheckMark);
        ivCheckMark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: saving the edited contact.");
                //execute the save method for the database

                if(checkStringIfNull(mName.getText().toString())){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: saving changes to the contact: " + mName.getText().toString());

                    //get the database helper and save the contact
                    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
                    Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getCourseID(mCourses);
                    Log.d("CURSORCOUNT","Cursor has " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()) + " rows.");

                    int courseID = -1;
                    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                        courseID = cursor.getInt(0);
                    }
                    if(courseID > -1){

                        mCourses.setName(mName.getText().toString());
                        mCourses.setCode(mCode.getText().toString());
                        mCourses.setCredit(mCredit.getText().toString());

                        databaseHelper.updateCourse(mCourses, courseID);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contact Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Database Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    private boolean checkStringIfNull(String string)
    {
        if(string.equals(""))
        {
            return false;

        }
        else
            {
            return true;
           }
    }


    private void init()
    {
        mCode.setText(mCourses.getCode());
        mName.setText(mCourses.getName());
        mCredit.setText(mCourses.getCredit());

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contact_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.menuitem_delete:
                Log.d(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected: deleting");
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private Courses getCoursesFromBundle()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "getCoursesFromBundle: arguments" + getArguments());

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            return bundle.getParcelable(getString(R.string.courses));
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

With the code Above, evreytime I select update I receive "Update Failed"

Update: DatabaseHelper Code

```
package com.example.v1z0.assignments.Utils;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.v1z0.assignments.Models.Courses;



public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts_table";
    public static final String COL0 = "ID";
    public static final String COL1 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL2 = "CODE";
    public static final String COL3 = "CREDIT";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                COL0 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL1 + " TEXT, " +
                COL2 + " TEXT, " +
                COL3 + " TEXT )";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Insert a new contact into the database
     * @param courses
     * @return
     */
    public boolean addCourse(Courses courses) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1, courses.getName());
        contentValues.put(COL2, courses.getCode());
        contentValues.put(COL3, courses.getCredit());


        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    public Cursor getAllCourses(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    }


    public boolean updateCourse(Courses courses, int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1, courses.getName());
        contentValues.put(COL2, courses.getCode());
        contentValues.put(COL3, courses.getCredit());


        int update = db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues,
                COL0 + " = ? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)} );

        if(update != 1) {
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }


    public Cursor getCourseID(Courses courses){
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME  +
                " WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + courses.getName() + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + courses.getCode() + "'";
        return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: try log this value and check if it is returning anything `System.out.println(databaseHelper.getCourseID(mCourses));` looks like it is not returning anything.

Comment: After line `Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getCourseID(mCourses);` add a line `Log.d("CURSORCOUNT","Cursor has " + String.valueOf(csr,getCount()) + " rows.");` Run, click OK, check log. Does  the line appear in the Log (should do). If so then is the value 0 rows? (if so then getCourseID isn't returning anything, which I suspect is the issue and would result in failed being toasted). tell us the result.

Comment: Result in log was D/CURSORCOUNT: Cursor has 0 rows. How do I fix this

Comment: OK so the issue will be in the getCourseID method (or before). So add as first line `Log.d("COURSEINDO","Course name is " + courses.getName() + " Course Code is " + courses.getCode);`. Run App, click OK, check Log. Are the values expected values? (valid course name and valid course code combination). If not then check that you are setting **mCourses** (as used by line `Cursor cursor = databaseHelper.getCourseID(mCourses);` in the onClick method). It could be that you need to set the values of **mCourses** before using the line.

Comment: D/COURSEINDO: Course name is Name Course Code is Credit
 D/CURSORCOUNT: Cursor has 0 rows.

Comment: Would you have a Course called **Course** with a Course Code called **Credit**? Perhaps you've sent and then extracted column names (COL1 and COL3)  via the bundle, although this should be apparent as you appear to set the EditText's with the values.